# Что такое «backdrop» и как использовать в «noty»?

Tags: javascript, jquery, noty

`noty` имеет параметр `closeWith`, который принимает в качестве значения массив из одного или нескольких следующих значений:

```
['click', 'button', 'hover', 'backdrop']
```

http://ned.im/noty/options.html

Что за `backdrop` и как его использовать?

---

Не могу понять что должно произойти:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function handler() {
    if (typeof handler.counter === 'undefined') {
      handler.counter = 0;
    }
    noty({
      text: 'Noty ' + ++handler.counter,
      closeWith: ['backdrop']
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-noty/2.3.11/packaged/jquery.noty.packaged.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hxgh1Lsr/

Comment: это слой под модальным окном. По клику на него окно будет закрыто, фактически означает закрывать при клике вне сообщения

Comment: @Grundy, ага, если добавить `modal: true`, то видно: https://jsfiddle.net/7hqw0x8z/. В общем-то я так и подумывал, что это клик «вне», но не пришло в голову, что это только для модальных сообщений. Странно как-то, почему не запилили и для **не**модальных,.. или такая фича есть? Не знаете случаем?

Comment: Нет, [обработчик для клика по backdrop](https://github.com/needim/noty/blob/master/js/noty/jquery.noty.js#L487) добавляется только для модального окна, просто потому, что в этом случае есть этот самый _backdrop_. Но всегда можно ловить клики самому и вызывать api метод closeAll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Ответ из комментария**
>
> это слой под модальным окном. По клику на него окно будет закрыто, фактически означает закрывать при клике вне сообщения

---

### Пример

То есть, чтобы увидеть эффект `backdrop`, нужно ещё добавить опцию `modal: true`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function handler() {
    if (typeof handler.counter === 'undefined') {
      handler.counter = 0;
    }
    noty({
      text: 'Noty ' + ++handler.counter,
      modal: true,
      closeWith: ['backdrop']
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-noty/2.3.11/packaged/jquery.noty.packaged.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7hqw0x8z/